# How to loop over Ansible variable names

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'd like to find all variables with the `myvar_` prefix and make a shell script that uses their names and contents.

```yaml
---
- set_fact:
   myvar_a: "a"
   myvar_b: "b"
   myvar_c: "c"

- name: Format Django webapp parameters
  shell: |
    truncate -s0 out.txt
    {% for param in lookup('ansible.builtin.varnames', '^myvar_.+') %}
    echo {{ param }}  >> out.txt
    {% endfor %}
```

The output is:

```
m
y
v
a
r
_
a
,
m
y
v
a
r
_
b
,
m
y
v
a
r
_
c
```

It iterates a string character by character for some reason.

How to get variable names into `out.txt`?
How to get the contents of these variables to `out.txt`? (ok, it'll be `{{ lookup("vars", param) }}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the lookup return you a comma separated list of variable names, not a list.

As demonstrated by the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: lookup('ansible.builtin.varnames', '^myvar_.+')
  vars:
    myvar_a: a
    myvar_b: b
    myvar_c: c
```

Which yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  lookup('ansible.builtin.varnames', '^myvar_.+'): myvar_a,myvar_b,myvar_c
```

There are three fixes possible:

1. use the [`wantlist=true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true) named argument of the lookup:

   ```
   {% for param in lookup(
        'ansible.builtin.varnames', 
        '^myvar_.+', 
        wantlist=true
      ) 
   %}
   ```
2. use a `query` instead of a `lookup`, [as `query` always returns a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true):

   ```
   {% for param in query(
        'ansible.builtin.varnames', 
        '^myvar_.+'
      ) 
   %}
   ```
3. `split` the string:

   ```
   {% for param in lookup(
        'ansible.builtin.varnames', 
        '^myvar_.+'
      ).split(',') 
   %}
   ```